# how to determine keystroke for a given character in Wingdings font in charmap?

Tags: fonts, keystroke

I basically want how to easily determine the keystroke value of a Wingdings character?  Looks like a very old version of Charmap used to have this functionality but no longer from what I see in Windows 7 version of the tool:

http://www.smartcomputing.com/editorial/fullsize.asp?guid=1C2531EB9E2F4ADA8155C9DBF9DBEA0E&image=00010557.jpg&caption=+Figure+4.+When+you+select+characters+in+Character+Map%2C+they+appear+in+the+Characters+to+Copy+box+in+the+upper+%3CSTRONG%3E-%3C%2FSTRONG%3E%3CSTRONG%3Eright+corner.+You+then+copy+them+all+to+the+Windows+Clipboard+by+clicking+on+the+Copy+button.+%3C%2FSTRONG%3E%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2FTD%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press alt and enter numeric code of char. 
numeric code has to be decimal, not hex.
And it has to be done on numpad.

so fo 0x7C enter Alt-124 |

Comment: Thanks, I would up vote this but only have 11 rep at the moment.